# Can i use TS Remote APP for Antivirus

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services

Is it possible that i install the Latest Anti-virus on server 2008 and other cleints can scan their folder/file/drive by using Terminal service remote APP.

Answer (score 2):

No.

RemoteApps local storage is still the local storage of the terminal server. You can access client disks and whatnot via RemoteApp, but they act as mapped network drives. RemoteApps have no access to the local memory. So you will not get any resident monitoring.

There is one caveat however, and if the AV software supports it, you might be able to ask it to scan a specific folder, and point it to the mapped network drive that is mapped to the local disk/folder you want to scan. That might work, but it would be pretty horrible (performance-wise).

Better off with a managed AV solution.

Comment: But then how some websites have the anti virus feature which allows user to scan their drives.

Basically i want that if some client have doubt on some folder or USB then he can scan that with Remote Anti Vir

Comment: Those websites install an ActiveX control onto your local machine, which probably loads the virus definitions off their remote server. If this is being deployed onto a website, then that's probably the best thing to look at.

Comment: So you mean that i can scan the drive from server as mapped drive but client can't scan from their end

Comment: Correct. If you ran the AV via RemoteApp, it would *appear* as if it was scanning locally, but it would in fact be scanning it over the TS Mapped Drive.

Comment: Is it possible that every user when they open AV then they can see only their drive as mapped drive in TS AV and they can scan it there without me involving